# Matrix multiplication in the examples section of R documentation

Tags: r, package, matrix-multiplication

I am producing a .Rd file to document a function in a package I have written. In the examples field I would like to include matrix multiplications using the %*% command but the `build & check' procedure appears to see the % as a comment and the check fails. Is there any way around this, other than using the crossprod() function? - this would be a little tedious since I would like to do numerous multiplications.

Stripping out most of the content of the file, it looks like this

```
\name{Travel data}
\alias{travel}\alias{trav.qly}\alias{trav.mly}
\docType{data}
\title{
Visits abroad by UK residents
}
\description{}
\details{}
\examples{
V<-rbind(cbind(B%*%K[1:84,1:84]%*%t(B),B%*%K[1:84,85:120]),cbind(K[85:120,1:84]%*%t(B),K[85:120,85:120]))
C<-cbind(K[1:84,1:84]%*%t(B),K[1:84,85:120])
}
\keyword{datasets}
```

Then the package checker gives me some output that looks like this

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘regspec-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:
...
> V<-rbind(cbind(B
+ C<-cbind(K[1:84,1:84]
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
C"
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post your code and a small reproducible example we can run.  Most assuredly `%*%` can be in your file.  See `?matmult` for examples.

Comment: @Carl Thank you for such a quick response. I am not sure I can provide reproducible code without including the whole package. Do these code excerpts help? I will come back with something reproducible if not.

Comment: results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: You don't define `B` or `K` in your example.  This means you won't be able to compute `V`.  This is more likely the source of your error, not using `%*%`

Comment: If you can answer your own question, feel free to post an answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker @Andrie Thanks for getting involved guys. Apologies for not putting reproducible code up, I was just hoping it would trigger memories in others who have wrestled with the package `check` process. I reckon we've got this one sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions. It appears the problem has already been addressed here [R message board](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265647.html). The key is to use `\` marks before the `%` as demonstrated in the [.Rd file for `matmult`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/man/matmult.Rd).